# Sort a list by a custom order

Tags: c#

I have an array of some types

```
private string[] linkTypes = {
    "dog",
    "cat",
    // and so on ..
};
```

> Yes, I could use an `enum` but in this case it has to be an array of
>   strings.

So now I have a List of objects called "LinkElement"

```
private List<LinkElement> links = new List<LinkElement>();
```

and these objects have a string property called "Type"

```
string linkType = links[index].Type;
```

**If linkTypes contains the elements "dog" and "cat", my links can only have "dog" or "cat" as their type.**

I want to sort the list "links" by the order of linkTypes.

Means the lists order contains the links with having the type "dog" first and after that the links with the type "cat" come up.

```
List<LinkElement> sortedLinks = ; // sort links

for (int i = 0; i < sortedLinks.Count; i++)
{
    LinkElement currentLink = sortedLinks[i];
    Console.WriteLine(currentLink.Type);
}

// Write down dogs first, cats after
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `linkTypes` (the private string array) is in the same class as `links` (the list of `LinkElement`), you can use LINQ's OrderBy with a simple lambda expression:

```
var sortedLinks = links.OrderBy(le => Array.IndexOf(linkTypes, le.linkType)).ToList()
```

Comment: yeah this is good but an argument is missing here `IndexOf(le.linkType))`

Comment: Sorry, code was written directly here and not tested. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons such as "alphabetical order" (string) "bigger number" (numerical types) etc. are accomplished using the IComparable interface.  You can implement this interface in your custom class to make instances sort themselves any way you like.  Read up on the interface here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx

If you have a fixed number of types, then you could use a quick helper method to return an integer for each object depending on its type, and compare the returned integers from each object to determine which one "comes first."

Comment: This is a good idea in general, but probably over kill for this situation.

Comment: I used to write quite a lot of them, but since we have LINQ's OrderBy, I don't recall writing even a single comparer. Admittedly,  using LINQ might be a little slower then other methods, but unless you have a real performance issue and can identify it's cause as the use of OrderBy, who cares?

Answer (score 0):

Implement either the `IComparer` or the `IComparable` interface. The downside of using the `IComparable` is that this has to be implemented by the class which is targeted for sorting, which means that in case you want to sort it a different way elsewhere in your code, you will not be able to do so using this mechanism. On the other hand, `IComparer` can be decoupled from the target class and implemented in multiple ways if you choose to, and depending on the sorting criteria in different parts of your application, you could apply one of these `IComparer` classes as needed.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c