# How to sort an IList with basis of another sorted list in C#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have two ILists (of different Types), `a` and `b`.
They are the same size because
**every a.G.Id  matches exactly one b.G.Id.**

`b` is sorted (because of an `OrderBy(b=>b.SortVal)`. Now I want to sort the list `a`.
(Classical sorting algorithms would help if I would have an `a.SortVal` and would just sort `a` without the help of a second list but that's not the case).

Comment: An alternative to do that in the C#-Code could be a stored procedure (SQL). But I should write a new question for that

Comment: "I didn't find a duplicate for this case !" Did you try anything beyond searching for an exact duplicate? What are your own attepns so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `.Include(x=>x.G)` when initialising `b`.
Then I defined and initialised a new list `bIds=b.Select(b=>b.G.Id).ToList();`

and

```
a = a.OrderBy(x => bIds.IndexOf(x.G.Id)).ToList();
```

did it.

(with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15275394/10357604 )

Answer (score 1):

```
var dic = a.ToDictionary(x => x.gId);

var aSorted = b.Select(x => dic[x.G.Id];
```

should do it

Basically creating a dictionary to identify `a`'s items by their `gId` and then using it while looping through `b`'s (sorted) items should return the items in `a` as ordered in `b`.

The dictionary is used to make lookups faster than a scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
a = a.OrderBy(x => b.FindIndex(b.G.Id == x.gId));
```

I've answered a question much like this one before - [Sort a list by a custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293353/sort-a-list-by-a-custom-order/47293434#47293434) - but it's not an exact duplicate.